# configure zend framework library path

Tags: php, zend-framework

i want to know where can i put the "library" folder in my zend project. Presently i have it in the location of my Zend server. This is my current "library" path:

```
E:\zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library
```

And here is the path to my "app" project:

```
E:\zend\Apache2\htdocs\app
```

Inside the "app" project, i have the folders like "public" and "application".

Now how can i integrate the "library" into my "app" project, without referencing it from zendserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app project u should have a library folder and should contain zend folder in that..so just copy library folder and put it in E:\zend\apache2\htdocs\app.

Comment: Ok, i copied the library folder from zendserver and pasted it inside my project folder, along side "public" and "applications". So now can i remove the library folder from zendserver? By the way, i have the following inside "application.ini" file: includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"  Do i need to modify it?

Comment: @dskanth..i think ur new to zend frame work..so better to download this example and try to run it.. http://akrabat.com/tutorial/simple-zend_form-example/   Here u can find zend_from_example.zip file and juzt unzip and put that folder in htdocs.. and run it..

Comment: Thanks kiran for the tip... very useful

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way it is to put those library files to the `library` dir (as in the other answers), but you should consider keeping them separated from the application.

It's easier to have separate `git` or `svn` repos for the libraries. Easy to update and maintain for multiple projects at once. Putting them in `library` will also won't work if you installed the libraries from the bundle, e.g. `apt-get install zend-framework-library`.

To have the libraries in any directory you want, just add it to the `include_path` array in the `index.php`.

Answer (score 3):

Quite often, you'll see a folder called like "`lib`" or "`libraries`" in your application *(next to `public`, `application`, ...)*.

In that folder, you'll put the frameworks you're using.

For example :

- `public`
- `application`
- `libs`

  - `Zend`
  - `Doctrine`
  - ...

To get Zend Framework, just [download it](http://framework.zend.com/download/latest), and unpack it to the right folder ;-)

Advantage : you'll be using the version of your choice -- and not the one, possibly outdated, provided by your environment.

And, as a reference, you might want to read the [**Installing The Zend Framework**](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/installing.the.zend.framework) chapter of the e-book [Survive the Deep end](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Please don't tell people to deploy 3rd party libraries to their application project folder, it is bad practice. Deploy your libraries to a path that you have access to, which is outside of your project, and reference it in your include path.

During development, it is fine to have the library in your project, for reference sake, but exclude it in your deploy script and instead have your deploy script either set an environment variable, or have it update your include path.